# How to change webbrowser html content without effecting page?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, ajax, webbrowser-control

I want to replace some string in html page with c# on webbrowser component. For example there is some text like "Welcome Page" which is loading that page by ajax.

I Want to vanish that and reload, I tried to;

> webbrowser1.document.body.innerhtml = webbrowser1.document.body.innerhtml.replace("Welcome Page","");

When I look for the string, "Welcome Page", It disappeared. So it works fine. But,
All the javascript functions stopped in the page. Page became a static page.

So thats the problem,
How can I change Any string in the page witout effecting any features of page?

EDİT:
I tried @ Mehran Hatami's solution. And it works fine. Now there is no javascript or other problems.

I solved with

```
foreach (HtmlElement link in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
{
    if (link.GetAttribute("id").ToString() == "messegetext")
    {
      MessageBox.Show(link.InnerHtml);
     if (link.InnerHtml.IndexOf("this is message which posted by ajax") > -1)
        {
            link.InnerHtml = "any new text to replaced I want :)";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only way for doing that, is to find the specific `HtmlElement` which contains `"Welcome Page"`, and modify its content. what your code does would wipe all the current html and their events out, and override it again.

Comment: Once Events are attached it only remove by remove event handler..@ Mehran Hatami,And Page is working if any string is replace with another, I attached a updated demo,check it..

Comment: @Ali you can answer your own question on stackoverflow, so instead of putting the answer in the question, move it to an answer and then accept your own answer.  This will help future visitors to this question.

Comment: stackoverflow give me error. Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.  So I m waiting